# optimize this redundancy in the cell function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want the average gain in a column without writing it by hand.

this is the reiteration I want to optimize ---> [ =AVERAGE(B3-B2;B4-B3;B5-B4) ]

what I need to do is take the value of the day subtract the value of the day before and do the avarage of that for every day in a month.

with what I have done, I need to click every cell by hand but I'm lazy and also want to improve that for sake of optimization.

how should I do that?

thanks and sorry for any mistakes in my english.

Comment: The AVERAGE (i.e. arithmetic mean) of the pairwise differences is mathematically equal to the last element minus the first element, divided by the number of elements minus 1 e.g. `=(B32-B2)/30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variant of this:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(B2:B32-OFFSET(B2:B32,-1,0),""))
```

You can see that it produces the correct result. Compare G2 with C34, which is just the average of the values in column C, which are the result of subtracting the prior day's value from the current day.

[image]